# Excluir dados em lista dinâmica encadeada usando linguagem C

Tags: c, lista

Boa tarde. Estou fazendo um projeto para a faculdade onde o professor pediu para criar um algoritmo com listas dinâmicas, onde uma lista deveria conter clientes e outra, produtos.
O objetivo do projeto é fazer o CRUD de ambas as listas, com a condição de que o cliente não pode ser excluído se tiver qualquer produto atrelado ao mesmo. O resto do algoritmo eu consegui fazer, mas empaquei na exclusão. Será que poderiam me ajudar? Como o código é meio grande (Cerca de 600 linhas), coloquei no Git, ao invés de postar em texto aqui.

https://github.com/GabrielManiza/estruturadedados/blob/master/trabalho_lista_final%20(3).cpp

Agradeço muito a paciência e toda a ajuda que puderem me conceder!

---

EDIÇÃO: A parte que está me dando problemas é como verificar se o cliente tem produtos. Preciso deleta-lo se não tiver e mante-lo (mostrando uma mensagem de erro) se houverem produtos relacionados. No meu código, a função que está responsável por isso (e não funcionando) é:

```
struct listacliente* remove_ordenado(struct listacliente *inicio, int x)
{
    struct listacliente *p,*q;
    p = inicio;
    q = inicio;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->info.codigo != x)
            p = p->proximo;

        else if(p->prod != NULL)
                {
                    printf("O cliente tem produtos cadastrados e não pode ser removido.\nPor favor, remova todos os produtos e então tente novamente.");
                    break;
                }
            else
            {
                inicio = removeInicio(inicio);
                return inicio; 
            }
    }

    if (p == NULL)
        printf("\nCliente não encontrado!");
```

Comment: Pode trazer para cá só parte que é um problema e que pode ser reproduzido. Pode fazer um [mcve].

Comment: Pergunta editada. Se achar que ainda está amplo, basta dizer, mas acho que lendo o código no GitHub fica mais tranquilo de entender o problema. Obrigado pela resposta!